# set multiple entity ( custom object ) to httpRequest

Tags: java, android, http-post

```
List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Provider", "UY"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("AccessToken ", "sdfl;kjsdg"));

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
```

I am adding parameter to http request like this.
But how can I add another Entity which is a java.util.Dictionary object.

```
Dictionary<String, String) dict = new Dictionary();
//add values to dict

httpPost.setEntity(dict);
```

will not work. What is the right way to do?

**UPDATE**:

This is what my server is expecting

```
 Dictionary ExtraData 

 string Provider 

 string AccessToken
```

The two String values I can send as `List<NameValuePair> nvps`. and set it to entity. but how about the first one?

Read that I cannot set multiple entity to httpRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your dictionary object to a json. Then you'll be able to post the dictionary object as string like you're currently doing.

Not exactly the answer you wanted, but I do it this way.

Comment: so one setEntity call is enough? ok I think that's the way to do. As the docs say that only one entity can be set to httpPost. Thanks

Comment: why dont you create a json with all the informations you want to post?  Then only one setEntity will be enough I guess.