# HttpPost Request set multiple entities

Tags: android, rest, http-post

I have a `HttpPost` Request and I need to set multiple entities for it. I know that `setEntity` is used to set single entity.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String json = "";
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
            se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                    "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));

            request.setEntity(se);
```

But how to set multiple entitiesin the request?

Comment: multiple entities can not be set on httppost. either you can create one json object with all available information or you can use HttpUrlConnection and send multiple entities by writing on connection stream .

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476222/set-multiple-entity-custom-object-to-httprequest

Comment: @Pr38y : In that case what will be the parameter type in my service function?

Comment: in case of HttpUrlConnection?

Comment: @Pr38y : In both cases.

Comment: for first case you can create jsonArray from all the jsonobjects and convert it to String and set as entity.